# Top output says my app uses 33 gigs of memory but how?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, memory-leaks, dotmemory

My app is run inside kubernates/docker container. Here is the top output:

[image: TOP output]

It shows that my dotnet app is using 33700 MBs but when I sum RES and SHR columns it doesn't add up to that number. I thought I need to add the VIRT column too but then I would see more than 55GB used which is more than the printed 33700 MBs number. So what exactly is included into it?

I tried to take a dotMemory snapshot but its size equals to that 1.7GB number shown in the RES column. How can I analyze how others (33-1.7) gigs are used?

I also have another app container that shows only 6 gigs used:
[image]

I don't see any correlation between the columns and the total used memory output.